# Qt 5 platform plugin "windows"

Tags: windows, qt, qt5

После сборки релиза проекта, перенес exe-файл в отдельный каталог. Перекинул все dll, которые он просил для запуска. В итоге при запуске выдает ошибку:

> This application falid to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows".

Как избавиться от этого? Как правильно компилить?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Вам надо создать папку platforms в папке с программой и скопировать туда 
qwindows.dll

В начало `main` добавить

```
QStringList paths = QCoreApplication::libraryPaths();
paths.append(".");
paths.append("imageformats");
paths.append("platforms");
paths.append("sqldrivers");
QCoreApplication::setLibraryPaths(paths);
```

Вот здесь всё подробно описано
http://habrahabr.ru/post/188816/

Answer (score 5):

Рекомендую воспользоваться переменной окружения `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1`, т.е. в cmd винды выполнить такие команды:

```
set QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1
myQtApp
```

Тогда Qt напишет, где пытается искать плагин и подробное описание ошибок

У меня (Qt 5.5, Windows 7 Pro) он пытался искать плагин в текущей директории в папке *platforms*. Туда я его и положил. После этого заработало без изменения кода и каких-либо других изменений